# list / get all SentOnBehalfNames in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro which creates a new email, send on behalf .... BUT I don't want to explicit use an hardcoded emailaddress, rather ask outlook which addresses there are set already.

I'm thinking about using a filter (like .... ends with "@myonbehalfdomain.com")

So in my example below: Eonbehalf should get the second emailadress which I can see using the dropdown 'from' field at new email.

Makes sense?

```
Sub CreateNewMail()

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strbody = "<BR><BR><BR>"

    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _

                "\Microsoft\Handtekeningen\custom.htm"


    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then

        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)

    Else

        Signature = ""

    End If


    On Error Resume Next

    Eonbehalf = getemailaddress(2)

        oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = Eonbehalf

        oMail.Display

        oMail.HTMLBody = strbody & Signature

    Set oMail = Nothing

    Set olNS = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Should the user select the address?

Comment: @Damian, No, I'd like to use the emailaddress that ends with "@certaindomain.com" .. so I have my main account (test@test.com) and an onbehalf (test@certaindomain.com). 

I want the second one (test@certaindomain.com)

OR if that is not possible: I'd like a string from my main emailaddress (test) so I can compile the sentonbehalfname myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I experienced an email can be available in Outlook to use as "Send on behalf" in 2 ways:

- As additional/separate account
- As an access to shared folder/mailbox in which case it's not visible in Accounts collection

For first case try loop through Accounts collection:

```
Sub getAccount()

Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    For Each oAccount In oNS.Accounts
    'your code goes here (read oAccount.DisplayName for example)
    Next oAccount

End Sub
```

In the latter case:

```
Sub getFolder()

Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    For Each oFolder In oNS.Folders
        'your code goes here (read oFolder.Name for example)
    Next oFolder

End Sub
```

******************************edit****************************

Try replacing getemailaddress(2) with `fnGetSecondAdress("theEmailDomainYouReLookingFor")`

and add below function to your code

```
Function fnGetSecondAdress(strDomain As String)

Dim strAddress As String


Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    For Each oFolder In oNS.Folders
                If InStr(1, oFolder.Name, strDomain, vbTextCompare) >= 1 And InStr(1, oFolder.Name, "Public Folders", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    strAddress = oFolder.Name
                End If
    Next oFolder


fnGetSecondAdress = strAddress

End Function
```

Comment: The latter case would be mine!

However, lacking basic VBA knowledge prevents me from finishing my task.
<code>

    Sub CreateNewMail()

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    For Each oFolder In olNS.Folders
        If InStr(oFolder, "certaindomain.com") Then
            test = oFolder.Name
        End If
    Next oFolder
</code>
So I want to you "test" as the SentonBehalf ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edited original answer, please check if it works for you. It might need additional tweak if the domain you're looking for appears in many shared folders/accounts in your Outlook